# Angular + Knockout issue with multiple bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

I want to start by saying that this is something I have to live with and I didn't made any decision on this.

We have an Angular Application in which we implement a Knockout component.

We apply the bindings to the component in the angular controller after all promises are resolved.

As it is a single page application if we go to another page and try to get back to the page with the knockout component we are getting the error:

```
you cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

This is manily because the first time we loaded the page all the bindings were applied.

We tried using the ko.cleanNode() but it doesn't work. I think because it is a componend and not a ko element.

I am wondering if the right approach is to recreate the knockout component or force a reload of the angular module (which I know works b/c if we hit refresh on the browser the bindings work just fine).

Comment: Can you apply the bindings to a higher level element that doesn't get removed when changing pages?

Comment: @DonovanM no, we can't, we are using that componen in just one page.

Comment: Where are you calling ko.applyBindings? Can you move that somewhere that doesn't get executed every time you change pages?